# Slick slider responsive not working safari

Tags: slick.js

I have a lot of sliders on my website which were all working perfectly with this code, then today (2 days before launch) all the slick slider responsive settings stopped working properly in safari mobile (works on chrome, edge and firefox). when you change the orientation, the settings don't change unless you refresh the browser in the same orientation.

I only changed some insignificant CSS and even reverted back to the previous version but it still persists.

I also tried removing each slider one by one, turning off any optimisation plugins.

I apologise for all the code, I know it's a lot but none of them work, so I don't know where exactly the issue is

I have tried to consolidate all the functions into one, but I'm not sure how.

I have tried adding mobile first which broke the desktop, I have also tried adding

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function() {
  $('.slider-name').slick('resize');
});
```

After each which didn't work, but I'm not sure about my placement, I also tried setPosition but again, not sure if my placement was correct.

I also tried

```
( function( $ ) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
      this.setupResizeHandler();
    }

  //sliders

    setupResizeHandler() {
      // Handle window resize event
      $(window).on('resize', () => {
        // Destroy the current slick instance
        this.carousel.slick('unslick');
        // Reinitialize the carousel with updated settings
        this.initiateCarousel();
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();

} )( jQuery );
```

And this kind of worked, but sometimes the slider would disappear entirely on resize.

The full code

```
 (function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.motpm-carousel').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 551,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.hero-slider').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 800,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        autoplaySpeed: 3800,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        arrows: false,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 551,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.motpm-discover-carousel').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1401,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 3,
              slidesToScroll: 1
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 1001,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 451,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              dots: false
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      $('.slide-prev-discover').click(function(e) {
        $('.motpm-discover-carousel').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.slide-next-discover').click(function(e) {
        $('.motpm-discover-carousel').slick('slickNext');
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.key-events:not(.events-2, .events-1) .motpm-key-events-carousel').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        arrows: true,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1001,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 901,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2,
              arrows: false
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 551,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              arrows: false,
              dots: false
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      $('.slide-prev-events').click(function(e) {
        $('.key-events:not(.events-2, .events-1) .motpm-key-events-carousel').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.slide-next-events').click(function(e) {
        $('.key-events:not(.events-2, .events-1) .motpm-key-events-carousel').slick('slickNext');
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.key-insights:not(.insights-2, .insights-1) .motpm-key-insights-carousel').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1051,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 901,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 2,
              arrows: false
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 551,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              arrows: false
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 551,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              arrows: false,
              dots: false
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      $('.slide-prev-insights').click(function(e) {
        $('.key-insights:not(.insights-2, .insights-1) .motpm-key-insights-carousel').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.slide-next-insights').click(function(e) {
        $('.key-insights:not(.insights-2, .insights-1) .motpm-key-insights-carousel').slick('slickNext');
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.pm-slider').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        variableWidth: true,
        dots: false,
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1001,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 2,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              rows: 0
            }
          },
          {
            breakpoint: 768,
            settings: {
              slidesToShow: 1,
              slidesToScroll: 1,
              rows: 0
            }
          }
        ]
      });

      var filtered = false;

      $(document).ready(function() {
        let filtered = false;

        function applyFilters() {
          const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

          if (screenWidth >= 768) {
            if (filtered) {
              $('.pm-slider').slick('slickUnfilter');
              filtered = false;
            }
          } else {
            if (!filtered) {
              $('.pm-slider').slick('slickFilter', $('.desktop-content-pm').parent().parent());
              filtered = true;
            }
          }
        }

        applyFilters();

        $(window).resize(function() {
          applyFilters();
        });
      });

      $('.slide-prev').click(function(e) {
        $('.pm-slider').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.slide-next').click(function(e) {
        $('.pm-slider').slick('slickNext');
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateCarousel();
    }

    initiateCarousel() {
      $('.pm-slider-content').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        infinite: false,
        fade: true,
        cssEase: 'linear',
        dots: false
      });

      var filter = false;

      $(document).ready(function() {
        let filter = false;

        function applyFiltering() {
          const screenWidth = window.innerWidth;

          if (screenWidth > 1000) {
            if (!filter) {
              $('.pm-slider-content').slick('slickFilter', $('.desktop-content').parent().parent());
              filter = true;
            }
          } else {
            if (filter) {
              $('.pm-slider-content').slick('slickUnfilter');
              filter = false;
            }
          }
        }

        applyFiltering();

        $(window).resize(function() {
          applyFiltering();
        });
      });

      $('.slide-prev').click(function(e) {
        $('.pm-slider-content').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.slide-next').click(function(e) {
        $('.pm-slider-content').slick('slickNext');
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

(function($) {
  class SlickCarousel {
    constructor() {
      this.initiateTestimonialCarousel();
      this.initiateNavCarousel();
    }

    initiateTestimonialCarousel() {
      $('.testimonial-slider-wrap').slick({
        autoplay: false,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        centerMode: true,
        infinite: true,
        dots: false,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav',
        responsive: [
          {
            breakpoint: 1221,
            settings: {
              arrows: false,
            }
          }
        ]
      });
    }

    initiateNavCarousel() {
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.testimonial-slider-wrap',
        dots: true,
        centerMode: true
      });

      $('.test-prev').click(function(e) {
        $('.testimonial-slider-wrap').slick('slickPrev');
      });

      $('.test-next').click(function(e) {
        $('.testimonial-slider-wrap').slick('slickNext');
      });
    }
  }

  new SlickCarousel();
})(jQuery);

$('.slider-nav')
  .on('init', function(event, slick) {
    $('.slider-nav .slick-slide.slick-current').addClass('is-active');
  })

$('.testimonial-slider-wrap').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide);
  var currrentNavSlideElem = '.slider-nav .slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + currentSlide + '"]';
  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
  $(currrentNavSlideElem).addClass('is-active');
});

$('.slider-nav').on('click', '.slick-slide', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var goToSingleSlide = $(this).data('slick-index');

  $('.testimonial-slider-wrap').slick('slickGoTo', goToSingleSlide);
});

$('.motpm-discover-carousel').slick('setPosition');
```

Answer (score 0):

I love [Slick](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), because it is normally solid out the box. Your situation is a weird one, I had to check this out for myself.

You state in your question the breakpoint events are not firing when you change orientation in Mobile Safari.

> Mobile Safari can be fickle at the best of times. What version of
> Mobile Safari were you testing in?

I've created an absolute minimal example of a slick carousel with multiple `slidesToShow` on standard breakpoints. Starting from smallest device and then breaking up using `mobileFirst: true`.

It's tricky to test mobile orientation breakpoints on here and jsfiddle. But in codepen you can test the orientation changes in Mobile Safari using the link below... (just click the `Result` tab once opening this link below in Mobile Safari)

https://codepen.io/joshmoto/embed/abXMJgB?default-tab=html%2Cresult

As you will see in Mobile Safari in portrait should look like this...

[image]

But when you rotate your device orientation, the carousel should automatically switch breakpoint settings to `sm` and should look like this...

[image]

Your described issue is 100% not expected [Slick 1.9.0](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) default behaviour.

In my basic [Slick 1.9.0](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) example, orientation events are working fine and switching to the desired breakpoint.

See my example code below...

```js
// breakpoints
const breakpoint = {
  // extra small screen / phone
  xs: 0,
  // small screen / phone
  sm: 576,
  // medium screen / tablet
  md: 768,
  // large screen / desktop
  lg: 992,
  // extra large screen / wide desktop
  xl: 1200,
  // extra extra large screen / full hd
  xxl: 1400
};

// init slick slider
$("#slick").slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: true,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 500,
  speed: 500,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  mobileFirst: true,
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: breakpoint.sm,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.md,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.lg,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xl,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: breakpoint.xxl,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 6,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
FIGURE {
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
}

IMG {
  width: 100%;
}

MARK {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-top: 3rem;
}

MARK::after {
  font-weight: bold;
  content: 'XS / 0px';
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  MARK::after {
    content: 'SM / 576px' !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  MARK::after {
    content: 'MD / 768px' !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  MARK::after {
    content: 'LG / 992px' !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  MARK::after {
    content: 'XL / 1200px' !important;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  MARK::after {
    content: 'XXL / 1400px' !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="slick">
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/q5Y5RCH.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/8HjXPXD.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/vUDcfcy.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/okTDHas.png" alt="" />
  </figure>
</div>

<mark>Breakpoint: </mark>
```

Here is the link to fully working code in CodePen...

https://codepen.io/joshmoto/pen/abXMJgB

As far as I can see, there should be no problemo in Mobile Safari.

Try use my example in your project and work backwards to debug the issue perhaps..

Hope this helps

Comment: HI there, thanks so much for this. I tried to create a codepen but I couldnt get it to work.

Nothing works, I have tried various versions of slick, disabling plugins, everything.

I thought maybe it was my CSS, but even the arrows don't appear/disappear when they should. The responsive settings are completely ignored. I have had to use a resize event listener and reset it, it works, but it flickers and it's so janky. 

I can try working backwards, it's so hard at this stage when there is so much code in place

I had the site a polished gem and now, with launch tomorrow, it's a mess :(

Comment: Are you able to tell me the correct position of set position? So I can try again - does it just come after each slider or within it somewhere? Thanks so much

Comment: What do you mean by "correct position of set position?"? You shouldn't have to faff around with all those extra event callbacks to get it working. It's a bit hard to tell without seeing your site. If your getting janky behaviour, have you got other animations running on the site at the same as the carousel animations? My example CodePen screenshots are on an iphone7 and it's working no problem. You might have confilcting js running that is causing you problems. Have you got any errors in your console?

Comment: Hey there, no errors. I did have animations but I disabled all my JS that was doing them. I stripped it right back to the bare bones and no joy.

In the end, I have recoded the whole thing with no breakpoints or add slides, just run of the mill sliders and have done all the responsivness myself with CSS. It's taken me the whole day but it's working. I'll investigate more when I'm under less time constraints and report back. Thanks for your help so far